# Django: TypeError: 'Like' object is not iterable (Ajax request)

Tags: ajax, django, iterable

I am not getting a clear picture regarding the Model (Like) object is not iterable.

**Error**

```
liked, created = Like.objects.create(question=create_id)
TypeError: 'Like' object is not iterable
```

**model.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likecount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^like/$', 'apps.question.views.like', name='like'),
```

**views.py**

```
def like(request):
    vars = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        tutorial_id = request.POST.get('tutorial_id', None)
        create_id = get_object_or_404(Question, id=tutorial_id)

        liked, created = Like.objects.create(question=create_id)

        try:
            user_liked = Like.objects.get(question=create_id, user=user)
        except:
            user_liked = None

        if user_liked:
            user_liked.likecount -= 1
            liked.user.remove(request.user)
            user_liked.save()
        else:
            liked.user.add(request.user)
            liked.likecount += 1
            liked.save()

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(vars, user),
                    mimetype='application/javascript')
```

**template**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-request" name="{{question.id}}" id="like">Request</button>

<script>
  $('#like').click(function(){

        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "{% url 'like' %}",
                 data: {'tutorial_id': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},

                 dataType: "text",
                 success: function(response) {
                        alert('You liked this')
                  },
                  error: function(rs, e) {
                        alert(rs.responseText);
                  }
            }); 
      })
  </script>
```

What I am missing here, can anyone explain me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should give datatype = json in ajax request.

Comment: _Where_ exactly are you getting that `TypeError` exception?

Comment: What does the `total_request` property (in views.py) do?

Comment: @LaundroMat - That was a typoerror. It's a likecount property.

Comment: That is not the actual error. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Here is a full traceback http://pastebin.com/a8AqDbXF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Like.objects.create(question=create_id)
```

Returns a single object (a `Like`).

So, doing `like, created = Like.objects.create(question=create_id)` doesn't work because there's only one item on the right, so it can't be unpacked (like if you did `like, created = 1`).

The method that returns the object and a `created` boolean object is [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(question=create_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But, if different user likes then the counter is not increasing.

Comment: @CodeIgnite That's an issue with your code logic, though.