# django like integration not working

Tags: python, django

I want to integrate like model in my app. Then this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007544/3762142) really helped me to start over it.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

But later i found one problem

> Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: content, creation_date, id, like, title, user, user_id

Well now  started question what is really slug field here ? in `name="{{ article_slug }}"`. Well nothing printed in html page `[name=""]` And then i found

```
    slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    liked, created = Like.objects.create(article=article)
```

this code is causing above issue.So i changed the code to `slug=slug` ==> `content=slug` then this time i am getting different error..

```
<p>No Article matches the given query.</p>
```

Ah .. this time i got it.. Now i changed to `name="{{ id }}"` .. hm nothing happened same error..

silly me.. definitely i am missing something really very simple. Anybody got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_object_or_404` works with a specific, unique field that is specified on the model.

Therefore ensure that the `slug` field is specified on your `Article` model class. Example:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    # remaining fields
```

Comment: see i given slug field in article and start over it , but error now is `'Like' object is not iterable` but each click one `like` object is created but count not increasing...

Comment: oh oh ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/22072567/3762142 helped. Thanks for your time

Comment: @iask Glad you managed to fix it by fully understanding your code. Nice!